# probability transition matrix markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I got an exercise in matlab were i need to solve two things.
I think i have solved the first part but struggle to solve part 2.

Info:

> A small version of the game Snakes and Ladders is shown in the figure below. You begin on square 1 and ending with square 9. In each case you toss a coin. Head equal 1 step and tail equal two steps. If you end up at the bottom of a ladder you will climb up to the top. If you end up on the head of the snake you will fall down to its tail. You need to finish the game by hiting square 9 with the correct step (from 8 to 9 will be 1 step). 
>   Because the probabilities are
>   "Where to go after the next step does not depend on what's has happend before", we can describe the game as one Markov chain.

[Snakes and ladders 3x3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPP8W.jpg)

**Problem #1**:
Solve the transition matrix for this chain.
**Problem #2**: 
What is the probability that you will finish the game (reach square 9) in:

- 5 turns
- 10 turns
- 20 turns

I am wondering if my transition matrix is correct (picture):
[Transition matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btd2e.jpg)

I am really stuck in problem 2 were i need to solve the 5,10 and 20 turns with **matlab** code.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with the transition matrix; for example, shouldn't there be a $0.5$ probability that you go from square $1$ to square $7$ i.e. that you roll a head on the first roll?

As for the computations:
**Hint** If $M$ is the transition matrix, then the $i$-$j$th entry of $M^n$, denoted $p_{i,j}^{(n)}$, is the probability of getting from square $i$ to square $j$ in $n$ steps. How could this be used to compute the probabilities you want given you can easily compute $M^n$ using MatLab?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your fast reply. I still struggle with the computations and will have to think hard about that. I know i can easily get the $$M^n$$ but my matlab knowledge is somewhat low. Should i make an additional vector that represent were im starting like A = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ] ? And then somewhat have matlab calculate probability that this vector end up with [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] ?

Comment: I think i have solved it now. I had to equal A*M^(n+1) to get it to work.
With this i get the probability to finish the game in 20 turns to be equal 85.39%. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If i take: (1,9) out of M^10 it will equals 1. It seems (from my transition matrix) that i will always get the value [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] on the last row regardless of what the power of n would be. All other values in the transition matrix change and seems "fine".

Comment: are you thinking of $(1,9)$ as row 1 and column 9?

Comment: $AM^{n+1}$ will give you a row vector where the $j$th entry of the matrix will denote the probability that you are on square $j$ after $n+1$ steps given you started on square 1

Comment: Someone replied to me that i only needed to take (1,9) out of : $$M^n$$ i.e $$ p_{i,j}^{(n)}$$  Thats why i replied saying it will only give me the value 0 (wrote wrong above) since the row always has the numbers [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1] regardless of number n.

Comment: If we look at the acctual boardgame. It is possible to finish the game with 25% probability in 2 turns.
For me to get the vector [ 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 ] I have to use M with the power of n+1. If i use n = turns it will just result in me having the vector [0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0.5 0 0 ] and it is not true( If we still are satisfied with my transition matrix ofcourse)

Comment: yes that's because the transition matrix is wrong; on the first roll you have a $0.5$ probability that you get to 7, not to 2

Comment: According to your transition matrix, it IS impossible to finish the game in two turns. My point is that it shouldn't be

Comment: Gosh, you are correct. I was approaching this matrix the wrong way. I was thinking since you cant stay on some of the squares. If i redo my matrix i get this: $$\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0  &0  &0  &0.5  &0  &0.5  & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  0& 0 & 0 &  0& 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5  & 0 &  0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5  & 0 &0 \\ 
 1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0  &  0&0 \\ 
 0& 0 &  0&0.5   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
 0&0  & 0 &  1& 0 & 0 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 0 &  0& 0 &0  & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$10 turns=79.59% ,20turns=96.08% probability.

Comment: Fun sidenote: How could we calculate expected value for n = turns to finish the game.

Comment: Yes that's the probability that you **have** finished by $n$ turns but not that you **did** finish in exactly $n$ turns; can you see the difference?

Comment: Based on your question, it's not clear to me which one you are looking for

Comment: Also, feel free to upvote/make as correct my answer if you thought it was helpful

Comment: Now i got somewhat confused. The question in my exercise cleary state: "What is the probability that you have reach last square(9) after 5,10 and 20 turns". And from that, would it not be the same thing we have just calculated? 

I will upvote since i really think you made your effort to help me out.
(How do i calculate the expected turns to finish the game in average out of a big number of games?)

Comment: that's fine then

Comment: The expected value would require finding the probability of taking exactly $n$ rolls to finish

Comment: So how would that be written in matlab so i could get an value like : "It takes approx 5.2 turns to finish in an average game"
To be clear, we are looking for the expected value μ (mean, expectation of the distribution).